# Select all objects with datetime less then x hours from now

Tags: django, django-models

I try to select all objects from a single model which has datetime field set less then 12 hours from now.

My view code:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# selects all events with date_time field set in future, and with reminder field active
events = Event.objects.filter(reminder=True, reminder_sent=False, date_time__gt=now)

# sets timedelta, as we want to filter previously selected objects to be max 12 hours in future from now
delta = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

# returns nothing, even if in database there are Event objects with date_time field set to 1 hour from now 
expiring_events = events.filter(date_time__lt=delta)
```

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Using `get` would only mean you select one object, with `filter` one expect multiple objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=12)
events = Event.objects.filter(reminder=True, reminder_sent=False, date_time__range=(now, delta))
```